# Was hat es mit der Trennung von Zwar und Aber auf sich?

Tags: grammar, sentence-structure

Immer wieder stolpere ich beim Lesen von Artikeln über eine Konstruktion, die ich so nie gelernt habe. Dabei wird ein Satz mit **Zwar** gebildet, die ergänzende „Aber-Partikel“ folgt dann allerdings erst im nächsten Satz.

> Zwar sollten Luxussanierungen, Wohnungszusammenlegungen und Umwandlungen in Eigentum wegen des für das Viertel beschlossenen Milieuschutzes verboten sein. Doch Spielraum für die Investoren gibt es genug, meint eine Mieterin.

*Quelle: [manager magazin](http://www.manager-magazin.de/immobilien/artikel/wie-die-samwers-im-berliner-haeuserkampf-mitmischen-a-1096678-2.html)*

Der Duden listet ausschließlich Ein-Satz-Beispiele.

Gibt es hier grammatische Regeln, die diese Trennung erlauben, oder zählt das zu der schafferischen Kreativität des Journalismus?

Comment: "Aber-Partikel" sind beispielsweise "aber", "jedoch" und "allerdings"

Comment: Sollte man ein Magazin als Massstab nehmen, dass nicht mal Groß- und Kleinschreibung auf dem Titelblatt hinkriegt? Ich halte solche Konstrukte für schlicht falsch (und danke für den schönen Euphemismus um die schafferische Kreativität)

Comment: Leider habe ich die anderen Artikel jetzt nicht zur Hand, aber es waren sicherlich nicht alle aus dem magazin(sic!) (Disclaimer: Ich lese das sonst nicht!)

Comment: Eine Anmerkung zum Beispiel: Auch hier ist die "*aber*"-Klausel (hier: "*doch*"-Klausel) mehrgliedrig. Wenn man vor dem "*doch*" ein Komma setzen würde, hätten wir innerhalb eines Satzes zwei Kommata und einen "*wegen*"-Einschub. Das wäre mich stilistisch ungünstiger als die vorliegende Variante. Ist aber rein subjektiv betrachtet...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

M.E. gibt es keine grammatikalische Regel, die einen Aufsplittung der beiden Teile der zwar-aber-Verbindung in selbständige Sätze verbietet. Im Gegenteil empfiehlt sich dieses Vorgehen m.E. sogar in bestimmten Fällen (siehe unten).

Dass es im Duden oder an anderer Stelle nur Beispiele für die Verwendung innerhalb des selben Satzes gibt, kann einfach praktische Gründe haben: Zur Erläuterung der *Konstruktion an sich* genügen kurze Sätze, bei denen die Teilsätze aus wenigen Wörtern bestehen. Bei derart kurzen Sätzen empfiehlt sich die Verbindung per Komma.

Längere Beispiele würden nur Platz rauben, ohne dem eigentlichen Erklärungsinhalt (Verwendung, insbesondere Position der Konjunktionen bzw. Konkunktionaladverbien [bzw. Konnektoren]) etwas hinzuzufügen - bis eben auf die Tatsache, dass ab einer bestimmten Teilsatzlänge eine Unterteilung per Punkt die Übersichtlichkeit erhöhen würde.

EDIT: Hier noch ein paar Beispiele aus dem [DWDS](http://www.dwds.de) (alle aus der ZEIT):

> **Die Zeit, 01.04.2016**: "*Premierminister Matteo Renzi schlägt zwar eine Reform nach der anderen vor. Aber Italiens Wirtschaftswachstum ist nach wie vor zu mager, und der Schuldenberg des Landes wird immer größer.*"
>
> **Die Zeit, 31.03.2016**: "*Denn er war zwar schon zuvor für das Tagesgeschäft zuständig und hatte den Gründer immer wieder mal während der Auszeiten wegen dessen Krebserkrankung vertreten. Aber er galt eben nicht als ein Produkt-Visionär wie sein Vorgänger.*"
>
> **Die Zeit, 31.03.2016**: "*Zwar mag auch das einen abschreckenden Effekt haben. Aber es ist sehr problematisch, wenn nicht speziell dafür ausgebildete Menschen plötzlich anfangen, das Recht in die eigene Hand zu nehmen und auf Verbrecherjagd gehen.*"
>
> **Die Zeit, 31.03.2016**: "*Das Album mit dem Titel Super ist zwar ein einziges 45-minütiges "Weißt du noch?", und in der Vorabsingle The Pop Kids fällt achtmal hintereinander die Phrase "remember those days". Aber für die Pet Shop Boys galten schon immer eigene Regeln.*"
>
> **Die Zeit, 29.03.2016**: "*Dabei fanden sich zwar immer mehr Hinweise auf eine Verbindung zwischen den Anschlägen in Brüssel und denen in Paris im November. Aber nach wie vor ist nicht klar, wer der Hauptverdächtige ist.*"

M.E. zeigen die Beispiele, dass eine Satztrennung dann beinahe unumgänglich ist, *wenn der "aber"-Teil (oder auch der "zwar"-Teil) **mehrgliedrig** ist*. Bei einem Komma-Anschluss wird der Gesamtsatz nämlich anderenfalls schnell unübersichtlich.

<sup>PS: Im DWDS hatte ich nach Sätzen mit "aber" am Satzanfang gesucht: `aber with $.=0` - Kennt jemand eine Möglichkeit, diese Suche mit einer weiteren nach vorangehendem "zwar" zu verbinden?</sup>

Comment: Ich gebe dir recht, dass es möglicherweise keine *grammatikalischen* Regeln gibt, solche Konstruktionen zu vermeiden, wohl aber *stilistische* - Ein Satz sollte eine in sich geschlossene Aussage bilden und alle Komponenten enthalten, die von Teilkomponenten "gefordert" werden - Deshalb gehören "zwar" und "aber" in denselben Satz - Sonst stellt sich beim Empfänger ein klarer "Hoppla"-Effekt ein. Die Satztrennung durch einen Punkt im Beispiel halte ich für "ganz" falsch". Ein Gedankenstrich wäre für mich akzeptabel, weil er signalisiert "wir sind noch nicht fertig".

Comment: @tofro Wie hältst Du es denn mit "*einerseits - andererseits*",
wenn der einerseits-Teil selbst schon aus mehreren Sätzen besteht?

Comment: @Uwe Stilistische Regeln sind im Gegensatz zu grammatischen keine "Gesetze" - Manchmal darf und muss man sie brechen. Wenn aber "Einerseits" und "Andererseits" einen Absatz weit auseinanderstehen, müsste ich mir überlegen, ob mein Leser beim Lesen des "Andrerseits" noch weiss, wo er das zugehörige "Einerseits" gelesen hat - Möglicherweise sollte ich dann keine paarige Konstruktion nehmen. Leider verfolgen viele Autoren auch heute noch den Ansatz "Es war schwer zu schreiben, deshalb muss es auch schwer zu lesen sein"

Comment: Ich lese zwischen den Zeilen heraus, dass "Aber er galt nicht als ein Visionär" ein vollständiger deutscher Satz ist.

Comment: @tofro: Die Regel ist mir offen gesagt zu streng. Ich wünsche mir etwas mehr Flexibilität und hoffe darauf, dass der Leser (wenn er ein "zwar" registriert hat) eigenständig vormerkt, dass wahrscheinlich demnächst - eventuell einen oder zwei Sätze später - das zugehörige "aber" folgt. Gerade wenn die zwar- bzw. die aber-Komponente weiterer Erläuterungen bedarf (und damit weiterer Nebensätze), ist für mich die Satztrennung stilistisch das kleinere Übel.

Comment: @npst Ja, richtig. Die Konjunktion "aber" leitet einen Hauptsatz ein, wie man auch an der Verbposition sieht.

Answer (score 4):

Das ist wirklich keine grammatische Frage, es gibt dazu keine Regel.
Stilistische Regel ist die, dass vielfach verschachtelte Sätze zu vermeiden sind.